# Usage of &allow-other-keys in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to make the most generic function and decided to go with keys as arguments.
I want to use `allow-other-keys` since I want to use the function with any key.

Let me show you:

```
(defun myfunc (a &rest rest &key b &allow-other-keys)
  ;; Print A
  (format t "A = ~a~%" a)

  ;; Print B if defined
  (when b
    (format t "B = ~a~%" b))

  ;; Here ... I want to print C or D or any other keys
  ;; ?? 
)

(myfunc "Value of A")
(myfunc "Value of A" :b "Value of B")
(myfunc "Value of A" :b "Value of B" :c "Value of C" :d "Value of D")
```

I know that `rest`is the remaining args but it has an array. It does not bind values `c` or `d` or even build them like an associative list (i.e to do sth like `(cdr (assoc 'c rest))`)

Do you have a clue or a solution ? Or maybe I am going in the wrong direction ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since when is &REST an *array*? The standard says *list*. In the case of keyword arguments, this is a *property list*. See `getf` to access elements of a property list.

One can also use `DESTRUCTURING-BIND` to access the contents of that property list:

```
CL-USER 15 > (defun foo (a &rest args &key b &allow-other-keys)
               (destructuring-bind (&key (c nil c-p) ; var default present?
                                         (d t   d-p)
                                         (e 42  e-p)
                                    &allow-other-keys)
                   args
                 (list (list :c c c-p)
                       (list :d d d-p)
                       (list :e e e-p))))
FOO

; c-p, d-p, e-p  show whether the argument was actually present
; otherwise the default value will be used

CL-USER 16 > (foo 10 :b 20 :d 30)
((:C NIL NIL) (:D 30 T) (:E 42 NIL))
```

But the same could have been done in the argument list already...

Comment: Sorry for the type confusion. Yes, it is a list, you are absolutely right. I'll have a look to `getf` in my case. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am still confused since `rest` has this value: `(C Value of C D Value of D)` but `(getf rest 'c)` or `(getf rest 'C)` give me `NIL`

Comment: Ok ... MY BAD. `:c`. Silly me. Thanks, @rainer